# JQuery Validate Plugin for Phone #

Tags: jquery, validation, phone-number

I am trying to create a custom validator method for phone numbers.  I would like to allow the user to enter the phone # in any format, ie. (800)555-1212, 800.555.1212, etc. then simply strip out the non-numeric characters, reformat the text in my own format and copy into the input field.  I have played with different methods, but can't seem to find the right combination.  My latest attempt goes something like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validphone", function(value, element, param) {
    mNum = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
    if(mNum.length != 10)
        return false;
    else
    return this.optional(element) || (mNum.length == 10);
}, jQuery.validator.messages.number);
```

This seems to validate as desired, but I can't find the proper way to put the reformatted number back into the input field.  Logically I think it should be `$(this).val(mNum);` but this doesn't seem to work. Perhaps it fails due to being called from the validation method?

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you would set the `val()` on `element` instead, in your arguments signature.